# Convert to IEnumerable<DateTime> result of LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq Query

```
var tListOfDates = tList.GroupBy(g => g.dateOfSlot)
                        .Select(s => new {s.Key.Value });
```

`dateOfSlot` is a `DateTime` value

How can I convert `tListOfDates` to `IEnumerable<DateTime>`

I've tried top cast the result, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the type of `dateOfSlot` ?

Comment: It Is DateTime.

Comment: @FulvioRogantin Then it does not have `.Value`. And if it is `DateTime?`, then just stop wrapping it in a `new { }`. Or better yet, replace the entire thing with more readable `tList.Select(g => g.dateOfSlot).Distinct()`.

Comment: Then why aren't you just selecting `s.Key` instead of creating an anonymouse type?

Comment: @GSerg thank you, I added that on the various tentatives I made.

I tried:

IEnumerable<DateTime> tListOfDates = (IEnumerable<DateTime>)tList.GroupBy(g => g.dateOfSlot).Select(s=>s.Key);

But I get this error

Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],<>f__AnonymousType6`1[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.DateTime]'.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Type of `dateOfSlot` is `Nullable<DateTime>` based on the comments

Answer (score 2):

You should drop *anonymous class* `new {s.Key.Value }` (you don't want it but `DateTime`):

```
 var tListOfDates = tList 
   .GroupBy(g => g.dateOfSlot)
   .Select(s => s.Key.Value);
```

It seems that `dateOfSlot` is of type `DateTime?`, not `DateTime` since you put `s.Key.Value`, not `s.Key`; if my guess is right you can put it as

```
  var tListOfDates = tList 
    .Where(item => item.dateOfSlot.HasValue)
    .Select(item => item.dateOfSlot.Value)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

A proposition,you take all dates and get the unique date by `Distinct`

```
var tListOfDates = tList.Select(g => g.dateOfSlot).Distinct();
```

Comment: thanks I did not thought about Distinct that simplyfies the query.

In any case I Tried

 IEnumerable<DateTime> tListOfDates = (IEnumerable<DateTime>)  tList.Select(g => g.dateOfSlot).Distinct();

and I have the same problem

Comment: Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__64`1[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.DateTime]'.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved with

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> tListOfDates = tList.Where(w => w.dateOfSlot.HasValue).Select(g => g.dateOfSlot).Distinct().ToArray().Cast<DateTime>();
```

May be there is something more that needed and the query can be simplified.

Comment: you don't need ToArray

Answer (score 0):

So you have an object `tlist`, which implements `IEnumerable<MySlot>`. We don't know a lot of `MySlot`, yet we know that every `MySlot` object has a `DateTime` property `DateOfSlot`.

The first part of your LINQ statement groups all `MySlots` in your `tlist` into groups of `MySlots` where every `MySlot` in the group has equal `DateOfSlot`:

```
tList.GroupBy(mySlot => mySlot.dateOfSlot)
```

Every group has a `Key` which contains this common `DateOfSlot`. So the `Key` is d `DateTime` object

The second part projects every group into one element:

```
    .Select(group => new {group.Key.Value });
```

`group.Key` is a `DateTime`. The problem is that a `Datetime` does not have a property `Value`. Are you sure that `DateOfSlot` is a `DateTime`?

It's not entirely certain what you want.

**I have an `IEnumerable<MySlot>` in `tList`, and I want all used `DateOfSlot` values in this list**

```
var allUsedDateOfSlotValues = tList.Select(mySlot => mySlot.DateOfSlot);
```

**But now I have duplicates, I don't want duplicates!**

```
var allDistinctUsedDateOfSlotValues = tList
     .Select(mySlot => mySlot.DateOfSlot)
     .Distinct();
```

This will have the same result as your code:

```
var result = tList.GroupBy(mySlot => mySlot.DateOfSlot)
    // result: groups of mySlots with same DateOfSlot
    .Select(group => group.Key)
    // result: distinct values of DateOfSlot
```